# Create a snip tool by Imitating snipaste software with powershell, but it does not go well

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, resolution

Do you know snipaste? It's very easy to use to snip a region of display and show the copied region on the topmost, so it's useful to contrast or input data.
However, this software cannot be used in company, so I decided to create one with primary function of snipaste , and I almost completed it...
Looks like there is something wrong when selected a region of display. Its position will be changed and its size will be scaled. I cannot figure out what happened.
It there anyone could give me a hand?

code like belows.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create form and set properties
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Snipaste"
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300)
$form.TopMost = $true
$form.FormBorderStyle = "None"

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300)
# $label.Dock = 'Center'
$label.Text = "INSTRUCTIONS:`n1. Alt+S to capture RIO.`n2. Alt+Q to minimize.`n3. Scroll to scale.`n4. Escape to quit."
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$label.Font = $font
$form.Controls.Add($label)

# Create picture frame and set properties
$pictureFrame = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureFrame.Dock = "Fill"
$pictureFrame.SizeMode = [System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode]::StretchImage
$form.Controls.Add($pictureFrame)

$global:bitmap = $null

# get screen's width and height, if necessary
# $mainScreen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen
# $screenWidth = $mainScreen.Bounds.Width
# $screenHeight = $mainScreen.Bounds.Height

# Add mouse wheel event to zoom in/out the picture
$pictureFrame.Add_MouseWheel({
        # Zoom out
        if ($_.Delta -gt 0) {
            Write-Host "pictureFrame widthxheight: ", $pictureFrame.Width, $pictureFrame.Height
            $pictureFrame.Width *= 1.1
            $pictureFrame.Height *= 1.1
            $form.Width *= 1.1
            $form.Height *= 1.1
        }
        # Zoom in
        else {
            $pictureFrame.Width /= 1.1
            $pictureFrame.Height /= 1.1
            $form.Width /= 1.1
            $form.Height /= 1.1
        }
    })

$form.Add_KeyDown({
        # Alt+S: snipaste function
        if ($_.KeyCode -eq "S" -and $_.Modifiers -eq "Alt") {
            # Hide form temporarily to allow user to select screen region
            $form.Hide()
            $label.Hide()

            # Prompt user to select screen region
            $region = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::GetBounds([System.Drawing.Point]::Empty)
            $regionSelector = New-Object System.Drawing.RectangleF($region.Left, $region.Top, $region.Width, $region.Height)
            $selectorForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
            $selectorForm.FormBorderStyle = "None"
            $selectorForm.WindowState = "Maximized"
            $selectorForm.BackColor = "Black"
            $selectorForm.Opacity = 0.2
            $selectorForm.TopMost = $true
            $selectorForm.Add_Paint({
                    $selectorForm.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle([System.Drawing.Pens]::Red, $regionSelector.X, $regionSelector.Y, $regionSelector.Width, $regionSelector.Height)
                })
        
            $selectorForm.Add_MouseDown({
                    $regionSelector.X = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X
                    $regionSelector.Y = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y
                    Write-Host "regionSeletor-1", $regionSelector.X, $regionSelector.Y
                })
        
            $selectorForm.Add_MouseMove({
                    if ([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::MouseButtons -eq "Left") {
                        $selectorForm.Opacity = 0.0
                        $regionSelector.Width = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.X - $regionSelector.X
                        $regionSelector.Height = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position.Y - $regionSelector.Y
                        # Write-host "regionSelector size: ", $regionSelector.Width, $regionSelector.Height
                        $selectorForm.Invalidate()
                    }
                })

            $selectorForm.Add_MouseUp({
                    Write-Host "release mouse", $regionSelector.Width, $regionSelector.Height
                    # Capture screen region and display in picture frame
                    if ($regionSelector.Width -gt 0 -and $regionSelector.Height -gt 0) {
                        $global:bitmap = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap([int]$regionSelector.Width, [int]$regionSelector.Height)
                        $graphics = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($global:bitmap)
                        $graphics.CopyFromScreen($regionSelector.X, $regionSelector.Y, 0, 0, $global:bitmap.Size)
                        $pictureFrame.Image = $global:bitmap
                        # Copy bitmap to clipboard
                        [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($global:bitmap)
                    }
                    $selectorForm.Close()

                    $form.Width = $regionSelector.Width
                    $form.Height = $regionSelector.Height

                    # Show form again
                    $form.Show()
                })

            $selectorForm.Add_KeyDown({
                    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
                        $selectorForm.Close()
                    }
                    $form.Show()
                })
            $selectorForm.ShowDialog()
        }
    })

$form.Add_KeyDown({
        if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Q" -and $_.Alt) {
            $form.WindowState = "Minimized"
        }
        if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
            $form.Close()
        }
    })


$global:formTop = $form.Top
$global:formLeft = $form.Left
$global:mouseDownPoint = $null

$pictureFrame.Add_MouseDown({
    $global:mouseDownPoint = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
    $global:formTop = $form.Top
    $global:formLeft = $form.Left
})

$pictureFrame.Add_MouseMove({
    if ([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::MouseButtons -eq "Left") {
        $currentMousePoint = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
        $deltaX = $currentMousePoint.X - $global:mouseDownPoint.X
        $deltaY = $currentMousePoint.Y - $global:mouseDownPoint.Y
        $form.Top = $global:formTop + $deltaY
        $form.Left = $global:formLeft + $deltaX
    }
})

$label.Add_MouseDown({
    $global:mouseDownPoint = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
    $global:formTop = $form.Top
    $global:formLeft = $form.Left
})

$label.Add_MouseMove({
    if ([System.Windows.Forms.Control]::MouseButtons -eq "Left") {
        $currentMousePoint = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
        $deltaX = $currentMousePoint.X - $global:mouseDownPoint.X
        $deltaY = $currentMousePoint.Y - $global:mouseDownPoint.Y
        $form.Top = $global:formTop + $deltaY
        $form.Left = $global:formLeft + $deltaX
    }
})

# Show the form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

I want the copied region could be shown correctly.

Comment: I've seen issue like this in c#.  Usually solution is not to put controls directly into a form.  Instead add a panel to the form and place controls inside the panel.

Comment: It’s *probably* to do with the DPI Awareness mode the application (i.e. Powershell) is running in, and your display settings being > 100% scaling. Check your display scaling, and as a test, set it to 100% and see if it all starts working - at least that will tell you if the issue is DPI Awareness, and you’ll have an avenue to research for a fix. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows for more.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

It's a DPI Awareness issue - scroll down to the code and add it at the start of your script.

### Long Version

I've tried your code locally and I'm pretty sure the issue is DPI Awareness, or lack of it in your script. Go make a cup of tea, have a nice sit down and then read on :-)...

### Background

I've got 2 screens on my setup:

- **Screen 1** - a 1920 x 1080 laptop screen at **150%** scaling
- **Screen 2** - a 5120 x 1440 ultrawide at **100%** scaling

They're arranged like this:

[image]

### Test with 100% Scaling

This is my desktop at **100%** scaling on **Screen 2**:

[image]

If I run your script as-is from a PowerShell console on **Screen 2** (100% scaling) and click/drag the mouse around the bounds of the Task Manager window I see this popup generated by your script (red border added by me for emphasis):

[image]

### Test with 150% Scaling

If I change the scaling on **Screen 2** to **150%** my desktop looks like this:

[image]

and when I run your script and drag to select Task Manager again I see *this* popup instead:

[image]

with Task Manager no longer centred in the popup even though I dragged the mouse from top-left to bottom-right of that window.

Notice also how the Task Manager window in the popup appears to be bigger than the real application - about half as big again, or 150%.

It looks like something has calculated the capture coordinates incorrectly.

### So what's going wrong?

By default, powershell.exe and pwsh.exe are "DPI Unaware", which means that any graphics operations performed by Windows Forms are drawn in-memory at **100%** scale regardless of the screen settings, and Windows will **stretch the application window** to match the scaling factor configured for the screen in Display Settings.

That's why in the second example the screen capture of Task Manager is larger than the original application - it's captured at 100%, and Windows Forms draws it at 100% in the popup but then Windows stretches the form and the image to 150% to display it on screen.

Your dimensions in your code are effectively "virtual pixel" sizes not "physical pixel" sizes. This is basically to support scaling in legacy applications that have no idea about display scaling (hence DPI Unaware).

To fix that you'll need to make your script DPI Aware - more specifically, "Per Monitor" DPI Aware. Then, the dimensions in your code will represent "physical pixel" sizes because Windows will leave your application to perform graphical scaling. Whether you actually *do* the scaling or not is up to you, but your code can now work in physical pixels.

### The Fix

The solution is to tell Windows that your script is DPI Aware - unfortunately you'll need to dive into Win32 P/Invoke to do this, but here's the code you need to do that:

```
$pinvoke = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Win32
{
    public static class NativeMethods
    {

        public const int S_OK = 0;

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/ne-shellscalingapi-process_dpi_awareness
        public enum PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS
        {
            PROCESS_DPI_UNAWARE = 0,
            PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE = 1,
            PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE = 2
        }

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getprocessdpiawareness
        [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
        public static extern int GetProcessDpiAwareness(
            IntPtr hprocess,
            ref PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS value
        );

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-setprocessdpiawareness
        [DllImport("Shcore.dll")]
        public static extern int SetProcessDpiAwareness(
            PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS value
        );

    }
}
"@;

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $pinvoke;

$dpiAwareness = "PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE";
$hresult = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetProcessDpiAwareness([IntPtr]::Zero, [ref] $dpiAwareness);
if( $hresult -ne [Win32.NativeMethods]::S_OK )
{
    throw "failed to get dpi awareness with hresult '$hresult'";
}
write-host "current DPI Awareness = $dpiAwareness";

# this will return -2147024891 => 0x80070005 => E_ACCESSDENIED if called more than once
$hresult = [Win32.NativeMethods]::SetProcessDpiAwareness("PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE");
if( $hresult -ne [Win32.NativeMethods]::S_OK )
{
    throw "failed to set dpi awareness with hresult '$hresult'";
}
```

Note that `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE` is also called `PerMonitor`.

One you've run that, the rest of your code will work as-is at any scaling factor.

### Test with 150% Scaling (PerMonitor)

Here's my desktop again at **150%** scaling on **Screen 2**:

[image]

and if I click/drag Task Manager *now* I see this:

[image]

and Task Manager is shown in the correct position in the popup and at the correct size.

Note that changing the DPI Awareness *might* have implications for other code you run in the same PowerShell session as the DPI Awareness will be defined until you exit powershell.exe or pwsh.exe.

There's also a more advanced DPI Awareness mode "PerMonitorV2" that you might want to read about which can be set using `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext` but this requires Windows 10+.

DPI Awareness is a vast topic so here's a link to an entry-point for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74933876/15339544 for the dpi awareness context signature

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. These codes almost solved my problem. Actually, I also doubted DPI awareness, but I have no idea how to deal with it. Thank you.
I'm aware that [Win32.NativeMethods]::SetProcessDpiAwareness will throw  an error when run this code twice. Could you show me what happened?