PS Disable WinForm DPI scaling on my Application completely
I am building a WinForm application in Powershell with some controls in WPF added to it as childhosts/elementhost(s). And im having a hard time disabling Windows DPI-scaling for the WinForm window, no matter how i try..
With this code at the top of my PS script
`# Check if the process is already DPI aware
if (-not ([System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DpiAwarenessContext -eq 'None')) {
    Write-Host "Process is already DPI aware."
}
else {
    # Define the Windows API function signature to set DPI awareness
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        public class DPIAwareness
        {
            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
        }
"@

    # Set the process DPI awareness
    [DPIAwareness]::SetProcessDPIAware()

    Write-Host "Process DPI awareness set successfully."
}

I get the return

"Process is already DPI aware."

And i dont want my WinForm to scale when changing Windows DPI scale from 100% to 125% at all. Because at work i have two monitors and GPO policies forcing strange things to happen to my application. Like for example the app looks just fine on my home computer at 100% DPI scaling in Windows. But at work i had to go into the executable > Compability > Change high DPI settings (Change settings for all users) and tick [High DPI scaling override - System (Enhanced). Then my WinForm executable looked perfect.
but as soon as i drag and drop the WinForm window between my two monitors the scaling occur from 100% monitor over to 125% DPI scaling monitor at the right. I want my WinForm to be static 100% DPI always like other applications as Mozilla Firefox, unlike MS Edge that scales aswell when dragging the window between monitors.
I also tried applying a manifest like this (without any luck)...
#Add the SendMessage function as a static method of a class
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

# Set the path to your manifest XML file
$manifestPath = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "PerkUI RemoteAppManager.exe.manifest"

# Read the content of the manifest XML file
$manifestContent = Get-Content -Path $manifestPath -Raw

And inside my "PerkUI RemoteAppManager.exe.manifest" i have info copied from Microsoft. But dont worked either.

For multi monitor setup you might want to try the 2nd snippet from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933463/why-does-powershell-console-incorrectly-size-my-gui-form/74933876#74933876. That might help

I tested these but without any success. Another strange thing is i actually went to try and switch my 1st monitor to 125% and my 2nd monitor to 100%. And launching the WinForm on the 2nd monitor that is now 100% DPI = weird scaling occurs. If i shift back again and open the application on my 1st monitor with 100% DPI it looks crisp. The monitors are the same brand (HP) and same size and resolution. So i guess its either our environment or a "bug" with Windows 22h2. On my home computer that is Windows 10 1803 my application looks perfect all the time.
